# Print to Array each a button is pressed from Textview

Tags: objective-c, textview, nsmutablearray

I am trying to print to array each time I press a button. Here is my code

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initwithObject:textview.text,nil];
```

The output I am getting is:
    :test

And then when I run the app again and press the button, the output is:

```
:the
```

What I want is when I press the button:

```
:test
:the
```

How can the data be saved each time I press the button into an array from Textview?

Comment: are you asking about data persistence between app launches? You would use either core data or keyed archievers for that. Googling both will give you lots of tutorials you can follow. If thats not the question, please explain it a little more detailed

Comment: I just want to the array to save the previous data once I press the button again to add new data.
OUTPUT:
the
test
out

the array should save everything and not keep the lastest value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, ok, i get it.
Each time you press the button you instantiate a new array by calling initWithObject.
That will overwrite your previous data every time. Instantiate the array once, maybe in viewDidAppear, and then use addObject: on the array, when the button is tapped. That way, your data will be saved.

EDIT: Heres an Example:
Your ViewControllers, assuming you are working on a iphone, has a mthod called

```
-(void)viewDidAppear;
```

Find it and instantiate an array you declared in the header file in there, using

```
array = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Now you have a global mutable array.
In your IBAction-Method (maybe its called buttonIsTapped or something) do this:

```
[array addObject:textview.text];
```

Thats it.

Comment: Do you mind writing an example? I am new to xcode. But I figured that the "initwithObject" was the issue. and Thanks so much

Comment: @user2402063 if you like it, you can accept the answer, and maybe upvote it ;)